# Getting Abort trap: 6 from Google Speech API

Tags: c++, google-speech-api

My specific question is how do you fix an "Abort trap: 6" error from Google gRPC (the Speech API).  More generally, as someone trying to ramp up on using the services, any tips on troubleshooting would be appreciated.  I haven't found good C++ documentation, just random hints around the internet.

I've got the streaming example [transcribe](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cpp-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/api/streaming_transcribe.cc) running successfully.  When I try to modify the code to pass in data from a microphone, my new code is crashing around the time it returns the first interim response.

I'm running with debug output, using `GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug GRPC_TRACE=api ./testSpeech`

The key difference I see in the output between my failing code and the working sample is the following:

Working log

```
I1221 07:01:42.805304000 123145420480512 completion_queue.cc:764]      cq_end_op_for_pluck(cq=0x7faa705043e0, tag=0x7000070b1990, error="No Error", done=0x10f9e3740, done_arg=0x7faa70467310, storage=0x7faa70467388)
I1221 07:01:42.805330000 123145420480512 completion_queue.cc:1297]     RETURN_EVENT[0x7faa705043e0]: OP_COMPLETE: tag:0x7000070b1990 OK
I1221 07:01:43.029567000 4652266944 completion_queue.cc:764]           cq_end_op_for_pluck(cq=0x7faa705043e0, tag=0x7ffee04f8350, error="No Error", done=0x10f9e3740, done_arg=0x7faa705304d0, storage=0x7faa70530548)
I1221 07:01:43.029637000 4652266944 completion_queue.cc:1297]          RETURN_EVENT[0x7faa705043e0]: OP_COMPLETE: tag:0x7ffee04f8350 OK
Result stability: 0.01
0   how
```

Failing log

```
I1221 08:00:32.559490000 4561257920 call.cc:1967]                      grpc_call_start_batch(call=0x7fe4f1033660, ops=0x7ffeec81b2d0, nops=1, tag=0x7ffeec81b630, reserved=0x0)
I1221 08:00:32.559509000 4561257920 call.cc:1566]                      ops[0]: SEND_MESSAGE ptr=0x7fe4f0571e00
I1221 08:00:32.559619000 4561257920 completion_queue.cc:764]           cq_end_op_for_pluck(cq=0x7fe4f0615f60, tag=0x7ffeec81b630, error="No Error", done=0x1036c18f0, done_arg=0x7fe4f0616820, storage=0x7fe4f0616898)
I1221 08:00:32.559650000 4561257920 completion_queue.cc:1297]          RETURN_EVENT[0x7fe4f0615f60]: OP_COMPLETE: tag:0x7ffeec81b630 OK
After write
I1221 08:00:32.559680000 4561257920 metadata_array.cc:34]              grpc_metadata_array_destroy(array=0x7ffeec81bc50)
I1221 08:00:32.559687000 4561257920 metadata_array.cc:34]              grpc_metadata_array_destroy(array=0x7ffeec81bc18)
After sending chunk
I1221 08:00:32.712612000 123145462775808 completion_queue.cc:764]      cq_end_op_for_pluck(cq=0x7fe4f0615f60, tag=0x7000099075d0, error="No Error", done=0x1036c18f0, done_arg=0x7fe4f040cc10, storage=0x7fe4f040cc88)
I1221 08:00:32.712655000 123145462775808 completion_queue.cc:1297]     RETURN_EVENT[0x7fe4f0615f60]: OP_COMPLETE: tag:0x7000099075d0 OK
I1221 08:00:32.712712000 123145462775808 call.cc:573]                  grpc_call_unref(c=0x7fe4f1033660)
Result stability: 0.01
0   what time
I1221 08:00:32.712930000 123145462775808 call.cc:1967]                 grpc_call_start_batch(call=0x7fe4f1033660, ops=0x700009907300, nops=2, tag=0x7000099075d0, reserved=0x0)
I1221 08:00:32.712945000 123145462775808 call.cc:1566]                 ops[0]: RECV_INITIAL_METADATA ptr=0x7ffeec81bc18
I1221 08:00:32.712954000 123145462775808 call.cc:1566]                 ops[1]: RECV_MESSAGE ptr=0x7000099075f8
E1221 08:00:32.712961000 123145462775808 call_op_set.h:947]            assertion failed: false
Abort trap: 6
```

Note the `grpc_metadata_array_destroy` calls in my failing version but not the working sample.  They occur for each chunk of audio samples I send.  Any suggestions from those more familiar with these APIs?

Edit: the assert that failed is from the following code segment in gRPC:

```
if (err != GRPC_CALL_OK) {
  // A failure here indicates an API misuse; for example, doing a Write
  // while another Write is already pending on the same RPC or invoking
  // WritesDone multiple times
  // gpr_log(GPR_ERROR, "API misuse of type %s observed",
  //        g_core_codegen_interface->grpc_call_error_to_string(err));
  GPR_CODEGEN_ASSERT(false);
}
```

Uncommenting the log says the error is "GRPC_CALL_ERROR_TOO_MANY_OPERATIONS", although I'm only processing a single audio stream.  The sample code just puts in a (seemingly) arbitrary sleep for 1 second after each write.

Comment: An Abort signal (signal 6) is *usually* caused by an `assert()` somewhere. Often a strong indication that you have violated some functions preconditions.